# How to remove entire array that have specific character

Tags: perl

I have a perl code that extract from .xls file. My .xls file is as below

```
NUMBER    NAME    ALPHABET
one       Jane        a
two       Adam        b
three     Josh        c
;four  
five      Agnes       e 
six       Mary        f
;seven 
eight     Lara        h
```

I want to extract the info and only take column 1 and 2. My perl code is as below.

```
     #!/usr/bin/perl

     use warnings;
     use strict;
     use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

     main ();

     sub main {

        my $filename = 'Book1.xls';
        my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
        my $workbook = $parser->parse( $filename );

        if ( !defined $workbook ) {
           die "-E-: cannot parse <$filename>.\n ", $parser->error(), ".\n";
        }

        my $worksheet             = $workbook -> Worksheet ( 'a' ) || die "-E-: cannot parse family pin list.\n";   
        my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet-> row_range();

        open ( my $file,"> output.txt");

        for my $row ( 1 .. $row_max ) {

           my @data;

           for my $col ( 0 ) {
              my $number = $worksheet-> get_cell( $row, $col );
              if ( $number ) {
                 push @data, $number-> value();
              }
              else {
                 push @data, '';
              }
            }

            for my $col ( 2 ) {
               my $alphabet = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
               if ( $alphabet ) {
                  push @data, $alphabet->value();
                  print $file  "@data\n";
               }
               else {
               push @data, '';
               }
            }     

     }

     close $file;

      print "done\n";
     }
```

The result is

```
    one a
    two b
    three c
    ;four 
    five e
    six f
    ;seven 
    eight h
```

I want to remove the entire array that start with string ";". I extend my code like below

```
        open ( my $file,"> output.txt");

        for my $row ( 1 .. $row_max ) {

           my @data;

           for my $col ( 0 ) {
              my $number = $worksheet-> get_cell( $row, $col );
              if ( $number ) {
                 push @data, $number-> value();
              }
              else {
                 push @data, '';
              }
            }

            for my $col ( 11 ) {
               my $alphabet = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
               if ( $alphabet ) {
                  push @data, $alphabet->value();
               }
               else {
               push @data, '';
               }
            }


      my @new_data = grep(!/;/, @data);
      my @latest_data = grep ( $_ ne '', @new_data);
      print $file  "@latest_data\n";


     }

     close $file;

      print "done\n";
     }
```

The output result produce like below.

```
     one a
     two b
     three c

     five e
     six f

     eight h
```

I don't want to be empty space. How i want to eliminate the empty space that produce result as below?

```
     one a
     two b
     three c
     five e
     six f
     eight h
```

I also try doing like this, but the result is same.

```
     for my $index (reverse 0..$#data) {
        if ( $data[$index] =~ /^;/ ) {
        splice(@data, $index, 1);
       }
     }
     print $file "@data\n";
```

Comment: just a quick note that your `grep` is excluding any element that contains a semicolon *anywhere* in it; you probably want ... `/^;/`...

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: You're creating empty elements when you do `push @data, ''"`.

Comment: I already try remove it, it still the same

Comment: Hi all, i update my case. Maybe can give you guys clear understanding

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to use Perl? You can get that exact result with `awk`. Also, your output is columns 1 and 3, not 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider checking column 0 of the current row before iterating over the rest of the columns; if the value starts with a semicolon, skip to the next row:

```
   # ...

   for my $row ( 1 .. $row_max ) {

       my @data;
       next if $worksheet->get_cell($row, 0) =~ /^;/;

   # ...
```

That way, you avoid pushing any new (row) data into the array.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It doesn't work for me

Comment: In what way does this not work?

Comment: the result is same as my first result (refer to my post)

Comment: You inverted the logic, from what I can tell. I *skip* the line if it matches; you're specifically executing the splice if it matches...?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get that result then you can use `awk`:

```
awk '$1 !~ "NUMBER" && $1 !~ "^;" {print $1,$3}' file.xls
```

That tells it to not print any row that contains the string `NUMBER` or begins with a `;`. It then prints the first and third columns and gives your expected output.

```
one a
two b
three c
five e
six f
eight h
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggestion. I need to use perl as in that file have many sheets

Comment: @daffodil In that case, your question is better on StackOverflow as it's related to programming than Unix/Linux.